# Specify probability to find a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-optimization

I have a Table which has 3 columns

**ID, name, and class**

Class can have one of the 2 values "A" or "B"

If I wanted to search a student based on ID, then my SQL query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE ID='4'
```

This gives me correct results.

Suppose if I know for a specific value 4 the probability to find this user in class A rows is very high than in class B

Is there a way to optimize this query OR

optimize the schema OR

should I partition the tables into 2 for class A and class B users?

(Or is it that MySQL already knows about these optimizations)

Comment: The value in `class` has nothing to do with the performance of your query.  The engine uses `id` to get the row and then fetches the row, where the values of the other columns are stored.

Comment: will partitioning of users table into 2(A and B) help me....or will it only increase the overhead?

Comment: What overhead?  I think you should read some of the documentation that MySQL provides on how databases work and how data is stored in tables.  There is nothing magic,but it is a system that has multiple interconnected components.  Databases offer mechanisms such as indexes and partitioning to speed queries, when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You asked whether knowing the probability of finding a row in one class or the other can affect query performance.

Don't even start thinking about this until you have many crore (many tens of millions) of rows to deal with. Seriously, Instead, spend your irreplaceable time learning about table indexing and getting your application finished.

Looking up rows based on `id` values is very fast indeed if your indexes are correct. Partitioning doesn't help performance much if at all for simple lookups. And, maintaining partitioned tables is a huge and ongoing pain in the neck.

A query of the form   `WHERE id = constant AND class = constant` can be made very near optimal with a compound index on `(id, class)`.

Good material to learn about SQL performance is here.  http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents

Answer (score 0):

You should have a table for `class` :

```
id | name
---+-------
 1 | A
 2 | B
```

Then instead of class names store class ids in users :

```
id | name | classId
---+------+-----------
 1 | u1   | 1
 2 | u2   | 2
```